# Check point version up failure (R76→R77.30) by iso through oracle vm virtual server

Tags: virtualbox, checkpoint, gaia

I am wrting this to ask you about Check point version up failure (R76→R77.30) by iso through oracle vm virtual server.

After mount iso , I commanded 「upgrade cd」 in virtual server.

### And then, the error message is as following.

bin/upgrade_start: line 16: ./upgrade: Input/output error

### PGRADE: Upgrade failed - exit status=126

Need your help.

Comment: Garrett, welcome to SO. This question, as written, is very difficult to follow and understand. You wont get many people looking at it when its like this. I would advise you to assure your question title is a more clear. I would say it as "Receiving error while upgrading my Check Point software from R76 -> R77.30". This way, others skimming can understand what you are asking quickly, get interested, and dig-in deeper.

Comment: Also, please explain some more context. Pretend I know nothing about Check Point software (the person who can answer you, may not). When you say "version up", I assume you mean "version upgrade"? When you say "I command upgrade cd", please explain what this means in more depth. Is it a screen that loads after you boot the iso image? Where is the error message coming from? Is it coming from Check Point? from virtual box? ... Yes, this is a lot of work, but thats what it takes to get an answer from someone volunteering their time to you for free.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a Standalone installation. We need more details about your log messages/files.

Another way to upgrade version is export manager database using migrate/export commands.

Install a clean 77.30 and restore this database into this new machine and  apply policies after restore.

Comment: Thank you for your comments ,guy.

Comment: I used VMware instead of Virtual box. And then, the issue was fixed.